# Is the usage of scala collection equivalents in slick operation is harmful?

Tags: mysql, database, scala, collections, slick

I have  tables `table_a` and `table_b` in my database and they are mapped in slick with TableQuery Objects. I need to copy a restricted set of data from `table_a` to `table_b`.

Let the table query objects be `tableQueryA` and `tableQueryB`. The logic for filtering and copying data is complex. So
I think of doing scala collection equivalent of table query object in a for yield and treat them as normal collections. But Everything happens in one transaction. The code looks something like this.

```
for {
    collA <- tableQueryA.filter(.....something....).result
    collB <- tableQueryB.filter(.....somethingElse.....).result
    ...... do something with collA and collB
    }
 yield ...something
```

Is there a harm doing this way, i.e handling as scala collections and processing them?
I am using slick 3.2

Answer (score 2):

By doing two separate `tableQueryX.filter().result`, you'll be executing two separate queries to the database. You could replace it with one query that joins two tables.

It's hard to say what is the better approach in term of performance as it depends on amount of `filter` or `where` clauses and what kind of indexes are used by the database to fulfill those. If you need a top notch performance, try both approaches and pick one that is the fastest.

If both of your queries yield big amount of data, you need to consider memory usage for your application too because all data is loaded before scala collection api can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any harm as long as data is less -  but better to filter out data at DB level to avoid any potential out of memory errors.